# Highcharts - Scatter plot: How to send information from clicks to a function with information about the click as parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, scatter-plot, highslide

I have a highcharts scatter plot, and I would like to add some custom functionality. For each click of the items in the highcharts (clicking the filters, datapoint, and the close button), I want to send information on the item that was clicked to the function "s" that I have included below. Can anyone help me with the proper code to do this? or whether it is possible ?

Here is my function S, I have written it so that it takes variables str0 through str6 and sends it to s.php as a URL variable for further processing.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function s(str0,str,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/s.php?o="+str0+"&q="+str+"&r="+str2+"&s="+str3+"&t="+str4+"&u="+str5+"&v="str6,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

For example, when someone clicks a datapoint, I want to launch that function, and include the x coordinate, y coordinate, the name of the series, the ticker, the "info", and perhaps the string "datapoint" as the parameters.

for a filter, I would like to include the name of the filter, and a string that says "filter".

For the close button, the same parameters as clicking a datapoint, but the string will say "close" instead of "datapoint".

Here is the full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Q1 Eanings and Outlook Forecast'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'site.com proprietary professional'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled: false,
                    text: 'Future Outlook'
                },
                labels:{formatter: function() {}  },
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                showLastLabel: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled:false,
                    text: 'Current Quarter'
                },
                    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            //return this.value + ' ';
        }
    },

            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 100,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 5,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}:</b><br>',
                        pointFormat: '{point.hover}<br><br><b>Current Q: </b>{point.y}/100<br><b>Outlook: </b>{point.x}/100<br><br><div style="text-align:center;">(click for more detail)</div>'
                    },



    cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                        click: function() {
                            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                pageOrigin: {
                                    x: this.pageX,
                                    y: this.pageY
                                },
                                headingText: this.ticker,
                                maincontentText: '<b>Detail:</b> ' + this.info,
                                width: 200
                            });
                        }
                }
            }



                }
            },



                    series: [{
                    name: 'Weak Guidance',color: 'red',data: [
            {x: 40,y:10,ticker:'KORS',info: 's', hover:'<br>br><a href="">read more</a>'},
            {x: 20,y:50,ticker:'LULU',info:'D.<br><a href="">read more</a>'},
            {x:0,y:0,ticker:'ZNGA'},
            {x:4,y:10,ticker:'JCP'},
            {x:6,y:25,ticker:'DECK'}
            ]},

            {name:'Strong Guidance',color:'green',data:[
        {x:60,y:60,ticker:'lulu'},
        {x:100,y:100,ticker:'GPS'},
        {x:70,y:66,ticker:'FB'}
        ]},

        {name:'Inline Company Performance',color:'darkgrey',data:[
        {x:50,y:50,ticker:'GIII'},
        {x:53,y:43,ticker:'BNNY'}

        ]}]





        });
    });


        </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
function s(str0,str,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/s.php?o="+str0+"&q="+str+"&r="+str2+"&s="+str3+"&t="+str4+"&u="+str5+"&v="str6,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 900px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; float:left;"></div>




    </body>
</html>
```

One thing that I have tried doing is this....

```
                    events: {
            click: function(x,y,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/s.php?o="+x+"&q="+y+"&r="+str2+"&s="+str3+"&t="+str4+"&u="+str5+"&v="+str6,true);
xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

But I am not sure how to get the information I need to correspond to str0, str... str6 etc

Comment: How are you creating the close button?  What is the "filter"?

Answer (score 2):

First, I would never create a function like `S`.  If you find yourself creating function with arguments like `arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4` then something is wrong with your design.  Ignoring that for a second and answering your question.

---

Highcharts allows you to setup a `click` event handler for many different components on the plot.  You set up these handlers in your plotOptions for that specific component.  For instance, if you want to handle a click event on a [scatter plot point](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.point.events.click), you set a handler like this:

```
   plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        // look at the variable this
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Inside the `function()` the `this` variable is the item that was clicked on.  In the case of a scatter plot point, it is the point object.  In this function, you are free to call your `s` function passing whatever data you want to it queried from the `this`.

Next, if you are creating the close button as a highcharts context button, you would set a click handler on that [component](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.onclick).  For that handler the `this` is the chart object.

Using this approach you can create a click handler for every component you care about.  From those handlers, you call you `s` function.